# which design pattern helps me to implement connection pool

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jvm

i am trying to create a connection pool for factory class ,which design pattern helps me to create connection pool .user want to specify no of connections and maximum connections externally.I have search for some time, some people proposed to use Singleton or put the initialization code inside some static block. But others said singleton is bad. So, what should be a right design pattern to use for connection pooling? Thanks.

Comment: Use readily available library instead.

Comment: apache dbcp works best for me!!!!

Comment: i am not only looking for database connection ..some tcp connections also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singleton is bad for a few reasons e.g. usually you cannot inject a Mock object.  If you provide a mechanism (or do not need) to mock test it, then I do not see a problem.

Please note that there are a lot of excellent connection pools available, I would first suggest to look into existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

**Database Connection Pooling**

Initially in my application i use `apache-commons-dpcp` and i faced lot of connection issues and latter after long analysis i use `bonecp`. I would suggest `bonecp` connection polling. And Strictly don't use Singleton patten. It will bring you big pain point once your application is go live.

**TCP Connection Pooling**

For TCP Pooling I suggest to use [Netty](http://netty.io/) and Take a look on [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) also.

Answer (score 1):

As previous commenters suggest, use libs like [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/), [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), [BoneCP](https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp) or [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/).

But if you want to "invent your own connection pool" and understand how it could be done for educational purpose, start with singletone and extend it to hold preconfigured number of your instances.